# Allow repeat badges for revisions?

Tags: discussion, badges, edit-badges

A while ago I earned the Copy Editor badge after spending a pretty serious chunk of time editing posts on Stack Overflow for grammar, content, formatting, etc.  I still do this from time to time, but I have a lot less motivation to do so since from here on out I know that I'm not going to be earning any more badges from it.  I don't want to seem like I'm "badge-grubbing," but badges do act as a strong motivator.

Would it be possible to create some sort of badge that can be earned multiple times for making edits?  For example, there could be a badge for "edited 100 posts" that can be earned multiple times, so that every 100 edits you make you get another badge to your name.  That way, you always have some sort of incentive to keep improving user posts and making the site cleaner and clearer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: They did add a list of the top editors to the [Users page](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) in the last major overhaul. That's been a nice consolation for some of us, but I agree that an additional badge might be a positive addition.

Comment: It would be nice to get the `Copy Editor` badge more than once...

Answer (score 4):

On a site with a million questions, and millions of answers, it seems like 500 edits for a gold badge might be setting the bar a bit low.

But I agree with the request, let this be a recurring badge that you get every five hundred edits, or whatever the bar may be if the badge conditions are reviewed and changed.

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas come to mind

- It sounds reasonable because that is a fair bit of time involved and the result is positive (e.g. for future readers etc)
- 500 edits for Copy-Editor isn't enough...maybe it's too easy to achieve this...
- Perhaps invest less time editing, and more time answering questions (even more useful than edits)...not trying to take away from your rep or contribution (689 answers is an amazing contribution (far greater than mine) and deserves a massive reward).

Comment: It is *not* too easy to achieve editing 500 posts!  Especially when just tag edits don't count...Editing is a **huge** part of the Stack Exchange system, it keeps our sites focused, clean, and concentrated.